# Custom entity lookup fails for non-string fields

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-rest

Given following entity:

```
@Entity
data class AuthorEntity(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    val id: Long = 0,

    @get: NotNull
    @Column(name = "resource_id")
    val resourceId: UUID = UUIR.randomUUID()
)
```

And repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "authors", path = "authors")
interface AuthorRepository : PagingAndSortingRepository<AuthorEntity, Long> {
    fun findByResourceId(resourceId: UUID): AuthorEntity
}
```

---

**Is there possibility to create custom entity lookup for `Rest Repositories` for a non-string fields?**

```
@Component
class RepositoryRestCustomization : RepositoryRestConfigurer {

    override fun configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config: RepositoryRestConfiguration?) {
         config?.withEntityLookup()?.forValueRepository(AuthorRepository::class.java, AuthorEntity::resourceId, AuthorRepository::findByResourceId)
    }
}
```

Above configuration causes `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID` upon creating an resource. However, when I change type of `resourceId` to `String` it works correctly.

---

**24.12.2018 - EDIT:**
I've configured custom entity lookup in a test project and I've got slightly different results. Creating and retrieving all resources works as expected. Although, accessing a single resource throws exception mentioned above.

Detailed stack trace:

```
2018-12-24 10:05:58.253 ERROR 27829 --- [nio-9002-exec-5] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.UUID
    at io.test.configuration.RepositoryRestCustomization$configureRepositoryRestConfiguration$2.invoke(RepositoryRestCustomization.kt:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.test.configuration.RepositoryRestCustomization$sam$org_springframework_data_rest_core_config_EntityLookupRegistrar_LookupRegistrar_Lookup$0.lookup(RepositoryRestCustomization.kt) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.EntityLookupConfiguration$RepositoriesEntityLookup.lookupEntity(EntityLookupConfiguration.java:214) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.lambda$invokeFindById$0(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:93) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:241) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeFindById(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:93) ~[spring-data-rest-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:520) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.getItemResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:333) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:117) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:791) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.13.jar:9.0.13]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: What exactly is the relationship between the config you have posted (relating to `AuthorRepository`) and the repository (`CouponRepository`) and entity (`CouponEntity`)?

Comment: @AlanHay None, I haven't changed names when pasting code samples here.

Answer (score 0):

You got that error because JPA does not know who to map `UUID` type in your entity with `varchar/char` type from db. The properties used in JPA entity should be of either primitive type, or of another entity type.

Comment: _"You got that error because JPA does not know who to map UUID type in your entity with varchar/char type from db"_ - I disagree. Additional configuration is only required when you want to use auto-generated `UUID` identifier.

_"The properties used in JPA entity should be of either primitive type, or of another entity type."_ - I disagree. In such case you wouldn't be able to define fields of type `String`, `Long`, `UUID` etc.